# New Port cannot be accessed

Tags: web, amazon-ec2, webserver

My server has jboss on port 8080,

Now I wants Tomcat too,

In tomcat 7.0.34 i had made the following changes

```
<Connector port="8010" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Now while I accessing the application from server local host it works fine..

But I was not able to access from Client side

Note:I had open the port 8010 from server amazon ec2

Comment: Windows? Linux? What OS?

Comment: It was Windows on server side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Windows firewall service is started.  If this is disabled, you will have issues.

Next, go to Control Panels and edit the firewall settings to allow port 8010 and 8443.  Test this by using Telnet 127.0.0.1 8010  and port 8443.